# Django form: two ModelMultipleChoiceFields, same model, different querysets, identical HTML names

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to set up two separate but related ModelMultipleChoiceFields on my Django form. Both fields use the same model but use different querysets. I need them separated so I can render them in different places, but I need the HTML names to be identical between the two so the POST variable names will match.

The closest I've been able to get is adding the fields with different attribute names - but that leaves me with two POST variables instead of one. I'd like the &tags and &more_tags choices to be consolidated into &tags.

**Forms.py:**

```
from django.forms import ModelMultipleChoiceField, CheckboxSelectMultiple
from myproject.models import Tag

class MyForm(forms.form):
    tags = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Tag.objects.qs_a(), widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    more_tags = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Tag.objects.qs_b(), widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

**Template:**

```
{{ form.tags }}
{{ form.more_tags }}
```

I've pursued a few different approaches but have gotten stuck - I tried consolidating the querysets into a single field and iterating through them in the template, but {{ form.tags.field.choices }} doesn't handle rendering. I also tried mucking through the form's clean method but got lost.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is 2 POST variables really so bad? What will you do with tags? Assign them to some model instance? How will form decide after POST with one variable + failed validation where to put those tags (which ones are selected)?

Comment: I need to pass the vars as described to an external service so they do need match.

Comment: I'd use two fields and merge data on server side, clean() should work here. Also, you can access form field from template using {{ form.fields.tags.choices }}